# Can't log into ubuntu 13.10, tried unity, cinnamon and gnome session

Tags: unity, gnome, cinnamon, guest-session

I try to log in on the normal log in screen and the screen goes black for a second and then kicks me back to the log in screen. I can log in with a guest session just fine, however. I've tried this with unity, cinnamon and good old fashion gnome, and the same thing happens with all three. I've looked through the log files, but none of them seem to have anything related to this problem. Right now, cinnamon and unity have been completely removed from the system.

Comment: This happened to me when I did a new install of nvidia drivers on my laptop.  I was still able to login the second go-around though.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to the guest account. Push Ctrl + Alt + F2

Login with username and password

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm

This happened to me and it fixed when reinstalling Unity and LightDM

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with lightdm. If reinstalling lightdm doesn't help, you may need to install a different display manager. The one I use right now is gdm, but there are others. To fix by using gdm instead of lightdm:

1. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1(or -F2/3/4/5/6) to get to a command prompt
2. Log in. Note: your password isn't shown, even as stars
3. Execute `sudo apt-get install gdm`
4. A while after starting the install you'll be asked about which display manager to use. Select gdm
5. Restart your computer and you should be good to go

If you do this, your login prompt will look different from now on.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I had this problem - I could login into Guest, but not into my user account. I had a problem with the user account, specially with the file `.profile`. But removing only the `.profile` file didn't do the trick for me. I managed to create a new user account. While on the login screen, open the **tty1** command-line window by hitting **Ctrl+Alt+F1** and run the following command:

```
sudo useradd -c "newusername" -m -s "/bin/bash" newusername --groups sudo
```

This command will create a new useraccount for you. Now remove the old user account by running the following command:

```
sudo userdel oldusername
```

This will remove your old user account, but not your `home` folder and you will be able to copy your important files to the newly created user account.

Then remove the old user account `home` folder by running the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/oldusername
```

This is the only way I solved this problem - with creating a new user account and copying my important files from the old user account to the newly created.