# Can't login in from LightDM

Tags: login, lightdm

But just LightDM. It worked this morning, just does not seem to be working this evening. This seems to occurred after a shutdown after a wakeup from hibernation. I always get a password denied sort of thing:

[image]

I can login into Gnome by running this in the `tty` *(which I can access)*:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo service gdm start
```

and KDE as well *(when installed)*, and using `sudo service kdm start` instead of the latter command.

Xfce also works.

To resolve this I have tried:

- Removed `~/.Xauthority` - to no effect
- Rebooting
- Changed password 5/6 times - may eventually get very annoyed and purge `/etc/passwd` and restore from backups
- Reinstalled Unity and LightDM - no effect
- Purged and Reinstalled **ALL** Desktops and Desktop Managers
- reconfigured LigthDM with `dpkg-reconfigure` - useless as it was done by the above and only sets the default desktop manager.
- Created a different user, that does not work - the same for the 'Guest Session'
- purged all recent installs

Here is `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=unity
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

And [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6827416/) is `/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log`. This is from the recent login, where I tried to login with the user `test`, and then my default login, `wmobbs`.

If anything more relevant to user/lightdm settings is available, ask and I'll post it.

Nothing appears to be a problem in `.xsession-errors`. Yes, there are previous questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394399/cant-log-into-ubuntu-13-10-tried-unity-cinnamon-and-gnome-session) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop), but those did not help in anyway.

All to no effect :-(

Using Ubuntu 13.10, Intel i5 Lenovo G570 *(integrated graphics, with Radeon HD 6370M discrete graphics - but I don't think this is the problem)* laptop.

I can still use the machine, I only really use it for work and stuff. I hope to solve this myself, but this will be useful if anyone can think of any ideas.

Comment: Look in the logs: `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` and `/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log`. You also didn't try (or you didn't write you did) reinstalling/reconfiguring the `unity-greeter`.

Comment: @falconer - `unity-greeter` went as a dependency, I removed all of LightDM as well as Unity, Gnome, KDE, even if it was not installed, I tried to `apt-get purge` it. I have checked the log, and added it.

Comment: @falconer - added log, added picture :-(

Comment: Found part of the problem  - `lightdm` cannot be stopped, therefore cannot be 'purged'...

Comment: Then just SIGKILL it. `killall -SIGKILL lightdm` . The greeter log doesn't show much about the problem for me. Try looking in the `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: @falconer - I seem to have it mostly sorted now... just fixing a few bugs. What I did was stop lightdm from being run on boot as explained [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/139025/178596), then booted, and I think I ran `pkill -U lightdm`, then removed the `lightdm` user. Then I could reinstall it. Now, to get back to a functioning graphical interface... :D

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/223634#223634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** messing around with keyboard layouts as well might of helped. For other people with the issue you could also used another login manager - e.g. [`gdm` (Gnome Display Manager)](https://askubuntu.com/q/152256/178596)

---

Seems sorted now... I think. I rebooted and purged one or two more things.

I managed to stop lightdm from running on boot as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/139025/178596), stopped all `lightdm` user processes with `pkill -U lightdm`. I could then purge `lighdm` and other slightly relevant stuff with various incantations of:

```
sudo apt-get purge ...
```

I also made sure that the `lightdm` user was removed, which seem to be why I could not fully remove it.

I just spotted when it removed the extra pieces of the kernel *(the kernel it was using - how did it do that?)*, including the bits with internet + graphics drivers. I then resolved that, and rebooted. This method probably is not recommended for anyone else with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever tried to delete everything in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` ?

To do this open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type the following command :

`sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

then delete everything in it, save it and reboot by typing :

`sudo reboot`

It solved my problem many times ago.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Purging and reinstalling should of solved that, I checked, and it removed the relevant config files.

Comment: Use ctrl+alt+F1 to enter the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For me,

```
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

was not executable. Making this file executable solved it:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/X11/Xsession
```

Source: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=748944#27

Comment: Please explain how to make that file executable as new users may not know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I used gdm3 instead as Lightdm was unable to change password

Purging and reinstalling may help